# My release dll is not working on other devices vb.net autocad

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am working on a project to make an Autocad addon for our engineering department. The project is nearly finished, but when I build the project and send the dll to my colleagues for them to add in autocad, it is not working for them. I can not seem to find a solution on the internet.
- I am using Visual studio 2019
- Autocad 2020
- I make the dll's by releasing it on a x64 platform
- They "netload" it in autocad and the commands that work on my device do not work on theirs

I hope somebody can help me, I am a self thought vb.net engineer for autocad, so I am not that experienced with the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signing thing should not be required - it works okay here.
Some things to check:

- in VS2019, did you set Copy -> false for the DLLs that are referenced ?
- when the receiver of your DLL does a right-click on the DLL (in the file explorer), is there an option to unlock the file ? If so, unlock it
- Use AnyCPU
- I always distribute the Debug version, maybe give that a try ?
- is there an error message that you can share ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sorry for my late response.
We stepped away from this method and used other means of programming.
Because of this, I did no use stackoverflow for a while.

I will try to test your solution and accept it if it's working, but I will have to request another working device for testing. My score is too low to upvote your comment, but thank you anyway!

Comment: A little bit late, but not all DLLs were copied that were referenced.

Answer (score 0):

It's trusted on your device but unless it's signed it won't be trusted on other machines. That is a security requirement to stop unsigned assemblies from running unknown script.

You can use a self signing certificate for your own machine but unless it comes from an known certification authority it may kick up a stink. You could attempt to add it to their Global Assemby Caches or to see some security is blocking it.

Comment: So this means that nobody can use the programs I make for them?